# Sphinx Autodoc: display the choices of a param from a variable

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

I have some parameters that accept only a set of values and these authorized values are stored into a list. Is it possible to use the content of this list in the docstring?

For example:

```
authorized_values = [1, 2, 3]

def foo(a: int):
    """Print an integer between 1 and 3.

    Args:
        a: The integer to print. The authorized values are: <authorized_values>.
    """
    if a not in authorized_value:
        raise ValueError(f"The authorized values are: {authorized_values}.")
    print(a)
```

This would ensure the docs is synchronized with the code. Because if I want to add a new authorized value, I have to update the code and the docstrings to ensure they are in sync, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a decorator to modify the docstring. Something like

```py
authorized_values = [1, 2, 3]


def doc_format(func):
    func.__doc__ = func.__doc__.replace("AUTHORIZED_VALUES", str(authorized_values))
    return func


@doc_format
def foo(a: int):
    """Print an integer between 1 and 3.

    Args:
        a: The integer to print. The authorized values are: AUTHORIZED_VALUES.
    """


help(foo)
```

Comment: Very nice, it works! I improved it a bit to support several values, I'm going to add it in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of [@kollie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21826899/kollie), here is the final version I use:

```
def authorized_values_in_docstring(**kwargs):
    """Decorator to replace keywords in docstrings by the actual value of a variable."""

    def inner(func):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            func.__doc__ = func.__doc__.replace(f"<{k}>", str(v))
        return func

    return inner

authorized_values = [1, 2, 3]

@authorized_values_in_docstring(authorized_a=authorized_values)
def foo(a: int):
    """Print an integer between 1 and 3.

    Args:
        a: The integer to print. The authorized values are: <authorized_a>.
    """
    if a not in authorized_value:
        raise ValueError(f"The authorized values are: {authorized_values}.")
    print(a)
```

So it is possible to replace several special keywords in complex docstrings.